# Div positioning under another div

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to place a div with a sentence just under a box but unfortunately I'm not able to get that sentence (div="underbox") under that box, it always stays at the top. I'm trying to figure out the problem but I cannot find any good solution to fix it.

Ideally, the overbox would hide the "underbox" div too, but first I need to be able to place it at the bottom of the blue overlay and then I will try to get that hover event right to hide that div too.

Any idea about how to do this?

```css
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.box {  
    cursor: pointer;  
    height: 250px;   
    position: relative;  
    overflow: hidden;  
    width: 400px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  
}  
  
 .box img {  
    position: absolute;  
    left: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
}  


.box .overbox {  
    background-color: #304562;  
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    color: #fff;  
    z-index: 100;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    opacity: 0;  
    width: 360px;  
    height: 200px;  
    padding: 130px 20px;
    
}  

.box:hover .overbox {  
    opacity: 1;
}

.box .overtext {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transform: translateY(40px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
}


.box .title {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .title, .box:focus .title {  
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
}


.box .tagline {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .tagline, .box:focus .tagline {  
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
}

.underbox
{
   position: relative;  
   float: bottom;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">  
        <img src="http://files.room1design.com/oldcity.jpg"/>  
        <div class="overbox">
            <div class="title overtext">
                Walk This Way
            </div>
            <div class="tagline overtext">
                Follow the path of stone, a road towards an ancient past
            </div>

        </div>
    <div class="underbox"><b>THIS TEXT SHOULD BE UNDER THE BOX</b></div>
    </div>
```

Comment: Not Clear what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

http://jsfiddle.net/gwes9ye7/1/

You can use `top:250px` on the class `overbox`.

Also, increase the parent class `box` height to `280px`.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
<html lang="en" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="en">
<head>
<meta content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" http-equiv="content-type">
<style>
@import url(http://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Open+Sans);

.box {  
    cursor: pointer;  
    height: 250px;   
    position: relative;    
    width: 400px;
    font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;

}  

 .box img {  
    left: 0;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
}  


.box .overbox {  
    background-color: #304562;  
    position: absolute;
    top:0;
    left:0;
    color: #fff;  
    z-index: 100;  
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    opacity: 0;  
    width: 360px;  
    height: 200px;  
    padding: 26px 20px;

}  

.box:hover .overbox {  
    opacity: 1;
}

.box .overtext {
    -webkit-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -moz-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -o-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    -ms-transition: all 300ms ease-out;  
    transition: all 300ms ease-out;
    transform: translateY(40px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(40px);
}


.box .title {
    font-size: 2.5em;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.1s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .title, .box:focus .title {  
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateY(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateY(0px);
}


.box .tagline {
    font-size: 0.8em;
    opacity: 0;
    transition-delay: 0.2s;
    transition-duration: 0.2s;
}

.box:hover .tagline, .box:focus .tagline {  
    opacity: 1;
    transform: translateX(0px);
    -webkit-transform: translateX(0px);
}

.underbox
{
   position: relative;  
   float: bottom;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<div class="box">  
        <img src="http://files.room1design.com/oldcity.jpg"/>  
        <div class="overbox">
            <div class="title overtext">
                Walk This Way
            </div>
            <div class="tagline overtext">
                Follow the path of stone, a road towards an ancient past
            </div>

        </div>
    <div class="underbox"><b>THIS TEXT SHOULD BE UNDER THE BOX</b></div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```